# Constrain generic type using another generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I have some base classes:

```
class BaseService<E> {
    constructor(protected entity: E) {}
}

class BaseController<E, S extends BaseService<E>> {
    constructor(protected service: S) {}
}
```

Then, I have a concrete instances of above classes:

```
class ArticleService extends BaseService<Article> {}

class ArticleController extends BaseController<Article, ArticleService> {}
```

**Question is**: can I somehow eliminate `E` from the `BaseController`?

When I state in `ArticleController` that `S` is `ArticleService` it should be enough - `ArticleService` is already defined as extending `BaseService<Article>`. I don't use `Article` in `ArticleController`, it is there only to satisfy the service definition.

Comment: Remove `E` and just use `S extends BaseService<any>`?

Comment: I'm wary of using `any` because most of times it defeats the purpose of type-checking. And to be pure, in case of `ArticleController`, it shouldn't be just _any_ type passed to `BaseService` but the one used in `ArticleService`. However, in this case I don't see there is a danger of losing any relevant information about typing... Am I missing something or it is really safe, simple solution?

Comment: Given the types you gave in the question I'm not seeing any type information loss since your controller doesn't know the entity type anywhere. Currently the type parameter is essentially unused.

Comment: @IngoBürk Could you turn your comment into an answer? I'd like to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove `E` and use `S extends BaseService<any>`. You're not using this type information anywhere so this is totally fine.